# Moderadores renunciando em massa na rede Stack Exchange

Tags: debate, comunidade, stackexchange

Recentemente, diversos moderadores estão renunciando aos seus cargos na rede da Stack Exchange em inglês, em especial depois de que a moderadora de diversas comunidades Monica Cellio foi destituída.

Alguns links relevantes:

- https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5193
- [Firing mods and forced relicensing: is Stack Exchange still interested in cooperating with the community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/176034)
- https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7512/3002
- https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/18133/3755
- [So disappointed to see the fall out this week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334025/176034)
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389906/540552
- https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6718
- https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1650/95
- [A very recent post asking people to go "on strike" was just deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334024/176034)
- [Can one take the entire Q&A base and move it to a new site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334035/176034)
- [An open letter on the state of curation and moderation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334015/176034)
- E muitos outros links relacionados.

Pois bem, aqui vão as minhas perguntas:

1. O que está acontecendo que está motivando diversos moderadores na SE a tomar a drástica decisão de renunciar?
2. No que isso afeta o SOpt?
3. Qual é a opinião dos nossos moderadores quanto a isso?
4. O que a SE acha disso?

Comment: Algo me diz que a ausência da resposta 4 irá responder as outras perguntas xD

Comment: Entrei em contato com o Nicolas para ver se alguém da SE aparece por aqui e não ficarmos no vácuo.

Comment: E já tem gente que pegou isso para fazer zoeira: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/31604

Comment: Mais um link: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5200

Comment: Spoiler alert: Nicolas não está por dentro da situação. Deja-vu?

Comment: No momento, temos na SE 1 moderadora destituída, 19 que renunciaram, 14 que paralisaram suas atividades, incluindo um que está de "aviso prévio" para sair e 1 ex-moderadora que renunciara pouco antes disso tudo acontecer abandonando tudo. Isso totaliza 35 moderadores a menos na SE. 1 comunidade já está sem moderadores e há 3 comunidades que só tem um moderador restante.

Comment: Já lá vão três dias sem resposta nenhuma... Acho que assim vai ficar ;)

Comment: Uma coisa que tem me impressionado que o problema real da rede que é as pessoas postarem "perguntas" que estão só pedindo para depurar um código porque a pessoa não sabe fazer isso ou então pedindo para escrever um código pra ela já que ela não sabe nem como começar e que descaracteriza o objetivo do que sempre foi o SO, nada é falando. A SE ignora isso completamente mesmo um monte de gente falando sobre. Nem para dizer que agora eles acham que isso é bom eles estão se pronunciando, quando mais falar que vão fazer algo para melhorar essa situação.

Comment: @Maniero Bem, não tenho acesso ao TL e não tenho ideia do que os CMs ou o staff estão falando para os mods que ainda permanecem. Mas eu conjecturo que a SE está simplesmente paralisada em pânico sem ter a menor ideia de como consertar a monumental KHd@ que fizeram e os CMs mais perdidos que cegos em tiroteio com medo de falar qualquer coisa para não piorar ainda mais a situação.

Comment: Mas nesse ponto eles estão paralisados há uns 2 anos. O que eu sei que acontece é que eles adotaram a estratégia de não responder. Já me orientaram fazer isso quando um usuário está descontente com algo. Claro que chega uma hora você tem que parar de responder alguém que está *trolando*, mas não acho que não responder seja solução. Eles não falam nada conclusivo sobre isso nunca, não é lá no chat , que eu nem frequento. Me lembro da primeira vez que fui moderador lá era muito bom, muita conversa sobre o a rede, se chegava em consenso. Na segunda vi que nada lá me interessava mais. Mudou a adm.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Eu espero mesmo que eles estejam em pânico. Tenho medo de que estejam seguros de que fizeram a coisa certa. E se continuarem com esse silêncio, a dúvida vai permanecer.

Comment: Já há uma resposta [An Update to our Community and an Apology](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334248/218708).

Comment: Pra mim isso aqui é dos mais importantes: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334259/140010

Comment: @bfavaretto eles parecem estar seguros que fizeram a coisa certa do jeito errado e que agora vão ter que lidar com isso. Também parecem estar seguros que salvo alguns usuários importantes que não serão mais moderadores tudo vai continuar  como está e ainda terão um monte de perguntas ruins (em outros tempos eu usuário outro termo) e que algumas vão passar e que gerará quantidade de conteúdo que vai gerar tráfego e ainda terá conteúdo antigo de qualidade (eventualmente algum novo também, mas raro), e tudo isso basta pra continuar do jeito que precisam pra ganhar dinheiro (o que é legítimo).

Comment: @bfavaretto não tenho a impressão de que estão em pânico, acho que eles estão exatamente do jeito que vc está temendo

Comment: Vejam que interessante, [um exemplo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334289) de uma pessoa que se sentiu ofendida pela Monica e ao mesmo tempo acha que a SE exagerou na reação. Pra gente ver que as coisas não são tão preto-no-branco.

Comment: Nunca é, e onde mora todo o problema, algumas pessoas acham que são e ficam impondo a cor preferida delas pra todo mundo. A minha briga é que isso não pode acontecer, isso ñ é bom pra ninguém, nem as pessoas que elas julgam estar defendendo. Mas até perceberem...

Comment: @Maniero nos já tivemos a nossa dose de SE também. A nossa sorte é que agora não temos nenhum CM designado diretamente a nós :)

Comment: @JorgeB. as vezes me dá vontade de postar lá no metão aproveitando isso o que passamos aqui e que a SE dizia que apoiava as ofensas que o CM jogava em cima da comunidade.

Comment: @Maniero não há melhor altura do que esta para fazer isso, os russos já aproveitaram também.

Comment: @JorgeB. O que os russos fizeram? Tem link?

Comment: Nova atualização: [An apology to our community, and next steps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334551/218708)

Comment: Muito boa intervenção lá: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334587/140010

Comment: Mais uma atualização [An update on my resignation notice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334750/218708)

Comment: [Official FAQ on gender pronouns and Code of Conduct changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334900/218708)

Comment: Aqui tem um link onde ela reporta tudo o que aconteceu com ela: https://medium.com/@cellio/dear-stack-overflow-we-need-to-talk-13bf3f90204f

Answer (score 14):

Vou tentar dar uma de jornalista.

De um lado, Monica Cellio, a moderadora possivelmente mais influente da rede foi "demitida" (perdeu status de moderadora em todos os sites que moderava). O motivo inequívoco foi discórdia com a diretoria do Stack Exchange sobre transfobia. O que não ficou claro foi a natureza da discórdia.

De acordo com a Monica em alguns comentários recentes no Meta principal e [em uma publicação](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5193) no meta de um dos sites em que é mais ativa, ela não defende nenhuma posição transfóbica. Do outro lado, a SE diz que chamou a atenção da Monica várias vezes sobre seu comportamento. Da última vez que ela sofreu uma chamada de atenção foi em uma sala de bate-papo exclusiva para moderadores. De acordo com a própria Monica (vide o link) outros moderadores discordaram de seus posicionamentos. Para evitar problemas [sic] ela saiu da sala e pouco depois perdeu os poderes de moderadora.

Como agravante, os funcionários da Stack Exchange não foram transparentes. A única resposta que veio dentro da rede foi um texto enlatado, repetido com.pequenas variações em alguns stacks. Uma funcionária deixou essa resposta para a publicação no link acima.

> We understand there are some folks upset about this decision. We aren’t going to share specifics out of respect for all individuals involved but this is a site reaching millions of people and we have to do what we believe fosters a spirit of inclusion and respect. When a moderator violates that, we will always do our best to resolve it with them privately. When we can’t we must take action. This is always done based on what we believe is best for all SE users.

Diversos posts no meta pedem esclarecimentos, sem resposta oficial. Porém, quando o Register (um tablóide) pediu esclarecimentos, [a SE respondeu](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/10/01/stack_exchange_controversy/):

> On Friday, we revoked privileges for one Stack Exchange moderator when they refused to abide by our Code of Conduct (CoC) after being asked to change their behavior multiple times. The disagreement stemmed from an interpretation of a certain policy, but our CoC is not up for debate.

---

Saindo do factual e entrando em opinião agora: transfobia de fato não deve ser tolerada, mas a falta de transparência no caso me faz questionar se a acusação tem base.

De um lado, a própria Monica diz que não tem problemas com o uso de pronomes preferidos e que apenas questionou a forma como isso deve ser abordado. Do outro, temos ex-moderadores LGBT que deixaram a moderação (antes do caso Monica) com a queixa de que o ambiente da sala de moderadores é tóxico, desgastante e preconceituoso. O caso mais recente, na véspera da "demissão" da Monica, foi a Aza ([link](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1195)). O único moderador que eu vi escrever (em inglês) um texto realmente elaborado sobre o caso Monica, o Caleb, foi transfóbico em seu argumento ([link](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6718)). Ele admite que tem uma visão divergente da diretoria sobre inclusividade e que um dia o desgaste o faria sair. A ironia é que ao darmos à Monica o benefício da dúvida, e tomada a sua palavra como verdade, o Caleb defende um ponto de vista diametralmente oposto ao dela.

---

Há pessoas que acreditam que ainda hoje a SE vai se pronunciar oficialmente no Meta, mas eu não tenho muita esperança nisso. A SE tem um histórico ruim quando o assunto é diálogo com usuários.

---

## Atualização

A SE acaba de lançar [um comunicado oficial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334248/221728). Ele começa com:

> Last week we made an important decision for our community. We removed a moderator for repeatedly violating our existing Code of Conduct and being unwilling to accept our CM’s repeated requests to change their behavior.

A SE afirma que a expulsão foi baseada no código de conduta atual, não em um possível código futuro.

A comunicação no Teacher's Lounge (a sala de bate-papo privada para moderadores) é sigilosa e pelas normas da rede não pode ser vazada, portanto não há como saber exatamente que palavras foram ditas por cada lado. Dessa forma, temos uma situação na qual temos a palavra da rede contra a palavra da Monica.

---

E voltando a opinião, dada a atualização acima, creio que a rede não será um lugar melhor enquanto não houver maior transparência com relação aos atos dos funcionários. Existe uma promessa vaga sobre isso no anúncio da rede, mas não acredito que isso acontecerá.

Comment: Se a carreira de programador falhar podes virar-te para o jornalismo ;)

Comment: Boa investigação e bom resumo de tudo. Também não acho que a SE vai se pronunciar, acho que ela deveria sim manter certo sigilo sobre o assunto em questão mas tb acho que estão fazendo isso da forma errada, daí acaba pegando mal para eles.

Comment: Em qual parte o calebe foi transfóbico? Não to com paciência de ler aquele textão todo agora hehehe

Comment: @Math Li aquele textão duas vezes e não achei nada transfóbico lá. O que achei espalhado em vários locais do metão e em vários metas foram algumas acusações falsas de transfobia para promover uma caça às bruxas.

Comment: @Math trechos como esses: *"If person A comes along and demands that I refer to them by their "preferred pronoun" (even if it is a mismatch for their genetic sex or the grammar of the language being spoken) and I refuse, that's considered an insult."* ---- "*(...) there is a progression in ideology (...)"*...

Comment: Estou tentando achar a transfobia, mas não consegui ainda. Acho que terei meu diamante retirado também. lembram quando eu falava no chat que faziam a legislação, a denúncia, o processo, julgavam, sentenciavam e executavam? Por isso que censura nunca deve ser tolerada, as pessoas sempre vão dizer que o que elas fazem não é censura, só é o que os outros fazem. Não existe meio termo em censura.

Comment: Não creio que o que está acontecendo é censura. Lembro de uma conversa que tive com meu pai, há muito tempo atrás... Ele brigou com um garçom . Eu pedi que ele se controlasse porque além de ter se excedido poderia ser preso. "Quer dizer que eu não posso chamar um neguinho de preto safado?" "Não pai, não pode. Rcismo no Brasil é crime e se o senhor for denunciado vai preso, porque o senhor foi filmado e há testemunhas". Ele até hoje acha que está com a razão. Eu até hoje sinto vergonha e evito certas situações sociais com ele. O que acontece no SE é a mesma coisa, não em forma, mas em natureza.

Comment: Este caso não é racismo, é injúria racial, e é ofensa conhecida universalmente e não é censura porque permite a pessoa falar assumindo uma punição proporcional se a pessoa sofrer prejuízo. Impedir as pessoas de falarem o que querem é censura, simples assim. A pessoa falar o que quer implica em ela ser punida se causar prejuízo. O prejuízo tem que ser demonstrado, não basta a pessoa dizer que aconteceu. E nunca, em hipótese alguma pode ser antes do ocorrido, quando você preventivamente é muito censura. Você censurou seu pai, mas aí é problema familiar seu e dele.

Comment: Pode ter sido pensando no bem dele, mas ainda é censura. Você censurar um familiar, um funcionário não tem o mesmo peso que censurar alguém que você não tem uma relação direta e e geralmente essas pessoas vão se entender até onde pode fazer e em algum caso procurar a justiça se não tiver outro jeito. Fica complicado as pessoas contribuírem em um site sob uma premissa, de repente a premissa muda unilateralmente e todo mundo é obrigado a aceitar isso e não pode fazer nada com tudo o que colaborou. Existe aí uma quebra de confiança bastante grave.

Comment: Mas a questão que já foi levantada por muitos é que parece que agora a SE adotou uma postura não dar valor para seus usuários, e que agora estes são só instrumentos para ela fazer o que quer. Dizer o que a pessoa pode ou não dizer é bastante fascista e é censura. As pessoas fazerem algo que causam prejuízo para outras pessoas deve ser punido adequadamente, seguindo um processo imparcial, o que a SE já demonstrou não ser capaz, é o que eu falei no primeiro comentário, você não pode fazer tudo.

Comment: @Maniero acho que enquanto a gente abstrai, a coisa parece censura. Mas veja as palavras do Caleb e aplique a um caso real. Suponha uma pessoa que nasceu geneticamente homem (vamos chamá-lo de Mario) mas que em algum momento fez transição. A pessoa tem uma nova identidade social, e agora seu nome perante a lei é Peach. Peach se identifica como mulher. Caleb deu a entender que, mesmo sabendo disso, não conseguiria se referir a essa pessoa por "a Peach" - no máximo por "o Peach", mas que para ser conciliador tentaria evitar o uso de gênero. Peach se sentiria ofendida.

Comment: Quando há um usuário ofendido e um usuário ofensor não é possível ser conciliador e dar valor aos dois. É uma linha divisória. A SE decidiu que prefere um ambiente no qual a quantidade de ofensas seja a mínima possível, para ser mais fácil gerir. Eu sabia que chegaríamos a esse ponto no dia em que o a política "be nice" foi implementada pela primeira vez. A diferença é que se naquela época eu achei uma má ideia, agora acho que é uma boa ideia.

Comment: Se sentir ofendido não é prejuízo por si só, tem que acontecer o fato e tem que ser demonstrado prejuízo, feito isso, ok, mas não feito isso, apenas se fez censura. Na verdade nem é exatamente o caso de censura, obrigar alguém **fazer** algo já parece algo até mais grave. E as pessoas sofrem tanto mais prejuízo sem perceber. A ques~tao é que nem todos concordam que é ofensor e quem é ofendido. E não é saudável uma instituição fazer todos os passos pra decidir isso. Isto é absolutamente autoritário, vai além da censura.

Comment: Uma última opinião antes que os comentários se estendam a ponto de justificar uma sala de chat: a meu ver censura é quando se impede que uma idea seja expressa. Qualquer pessoa que ache que pessoas trans não deveriam existir poderá continuar expressando essas ideias - mas deverá fazer com respeito. Negar às pessoas trans o tratamento pelo gênero com o qual se identificam não será mais tratado com vista grossa, só isso.

Comment: Ninguém falou que pessoas trans não deveriam existir, esta é uma maluquice que algumas pessoas inferem de uns tempos pra cá, o problema está na cabeça dessas pessoas. Ainda assim a pessoa deveria ter o direito de fazer isso, sob pena de que se causar prejuízo algo será feito dentro de um processo democrático e nunca autoritário. Eu defendo punição para quem cause um prejuízo assim. Eu não estou defendendo que isto é bom. Apenas estou dizendo que eu sei o que é censura, algumas pessoas resolveram ter sua própria definição para atender seus interesses.

Comment: Isso qui mostra o tamanho da maluquice: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334187/140010. A pessoa se sentir ofendida neste caso não importa. Quem fez a ofensa, aparentemente o Tim Post não será destituído porque ele não quis dizer o que a pessoa interpretou. Mas alguém dizer que uma pessoa pode ter uma atitude transfóbica que ela mesma vai definir o que é não tem nem o que pensar, essa pessoa já está errada antes mesmo de dizer, não cabe interpretação da intenção. Ali tem um claro caso de 2 pesos e 2 medidas. Por isso tudo isso está errado, não tem um critério realista e sensato, só ideologia.

Comment: @Renan Colocando de forma simples, o problema é o seguinte: Você vê que tem um usuário chamado RJ45 e por algum motivo precisa fazer uma referência a ele na terceira pessoa (por exemplo "veja mais detalhes na resposta **do** RJ45"). Aí que começou o problema. Ao usar "**do**", você está presumindo que RJ45 é um homem. Algumas pessoas então, quando não sabe qual é o gênero a ser utilizado, simplesmente não usa pronome nenhum e escreve algo como "veja mais detalhes na resposta postada por RJ45". [continua]

Comment: [continuação] Daí, algumas pessoas LGBTQI+ começaram a reclamar que recusar-se a usar um pronome é uma forma de discriminação. Ocorre que as pessoas evitam um pronome não para discriminar, mas sim para evitar encrencas ou por não saber fazer melhor. Foi isso o que a Monica tentou defender como o melhor e acabou condenada à fogueira por heresia. Já outras pessoas, querem bater na mesma tecla e mostrar que usar o pronome errado é um crime hediondo e terrível e que recusar-se a usar qualquer pronome também é mais terrível ainda e que portanto [continua]

Comment: [continuação] todos teriam a obrigação de descobrir qual é o pronome mais adequado para cada usuário (e dane-se se não houver qualquer coisa no perfil que mostre qual é) sob a pena de morte por fazer o contrário.

Comment: Não tenho nada contra LGBTQI+. Mas eu acho que o que está sendo proposto é simplesmente lunático. Não se deveria usar a bandeira da igualdade como muleta para implantar-se propostas malucas e ditadoriais, mas qualquer um que tente falar isso, já é taxado como homofóbico.

Comment: só pra dar uma perspectiva, eu não estou presumindo que o usuário é um homem porque uso o artigo masculino, eu estou presumindo que é um usuário. Os textos da SE estão cheio de artigos masculinos se referenciado para pessoas que podem ser homens ou mulheres. Estou seguindo o padrão da SE (que eu escolhi, eu poderia ter escolhido fazer diferente). Também uso o artigo feminino quando estou falando de uma pessoa, porque eu entendo de concordância (quando não erro por desatenção ou confusão na hora de executar na digitação do que pensei), o que é comum em mim porque tenho uma doença mental.

Comment: O que é complicado é exigirem você começar ignorar a gramática porque alguém quer assim. E dar um f0d@-se pra o problema real que uma pessoa tem para fazer algo porque alguém tem um problema que ela mesmo criou pra ela (eu falo de se ofender por algo que não é ofensivo, não falo de escolhas que cada um faz pra sua vida que eu sempre defendi que a pessoa tem esse direito, acho que a pessoa pode até se ofender também, mas isso não pode exigir que outras pessoas sejam envolvidas nisso).

Comment: Se começa assim todo mundo começa dizer que está ofendido e pede privilégio quanto a isso, aí vão ter que escolher quem serão considerados ofendidos e quem é só mimimi. Existirão os escolhidos. Lembrando que sou contra ofensas claras, de conhecimento universal, intencional e que pode ser punida de alguma forma mais ou menos justa depois que acontece. A comparação com a inquisição é muito boa. Lembrando que você começa ser obrigado a criar uma agendinha pra cada pessoa pra saber como chamá-la.

Comment: Por sorte Pablo Vittar diz pra chamar do que quiser porque qualquer um que vê esse nome usuário artigo masculino, e quem usa feminino é pra fazer *statement*, que é um direito da pessoa. Que bom que algumas pessoas são bem resolvidas e sabem o que é ofensa e o que não é. Que se responsabiliza pela confusão que causou. Sua última frase é o que resume tudo isto. Eu nem resolvi contestar o uso da bandeira de diversidade quando as pessoas querem um pensamento único.

Comment: Eu acho que vocês edtão preocupados com sanções e julgamentos que não vão existir, porque o novo CoC aparentemente ainda vai prezar pela razoabilidade. Eu não tengo acesso ao TL, mas o Snow tem, e por tudo que ele disse até agora no Meta principal essas situações não aconteceriam. A maioria esmagadora dos usuários nem perceberia mudanças.

Comment: Quanto a nós com o nosso idioma no qual não há pronome neutro, não precisamos nos preocupar com violações gramaticais. Todo mundo que debate questões identitárias e de gênero há mais tempo concorda que tentar usar @ ou a letra `e` como vogal neutra não resolve nenhum problema, apenas cria mais problemas. Quem se identifica como gênero flúido não se importa em ser tratado por ambos oa gêneros, quem se identifica como trans assume a performance de gênero e um nome adequados. Não me aprofundei em como gostariam de ser tratados em geral as pessoas não binárias, mas deve ser igualmente razoável.

Comment: Enfim, se Joana quer ser chamada por "ela" e alguém diz "não, eu descobri que você é travesti então Joana é ele", isso é uma clara falta de respeito e não deve ser tratado de forma diferente de um ataque pessoal. Isso já é conerto pelo CoC atual! Aparentemente a confusão toda foi porque a diretoria estabeleceu que isso deveria ser explícito, Monica teve uma discussão nada amistosa com.uma.diretora e foi demoderada por isso. A falta de transparência da Stack Exchange fez o caso atingir a proporçãp a qual chegou.

Comment: Não, tem um monte de maluco que prega veementemente que tem que usar um artigo neutro e inclusive usam o X no lugar. Por tudo o que você mesmo postou ficou claro que houve uma retaliação preventiva. Essas coisas sempre são um primeiro passo pra algo maior. Quem faz algo atropelado assim faz coisa pior, ainda mais não admitindo o erro. E mais eles já admitiram erro antes, nunca em coisas graves, e voltaram a fazer, então eles admitirem erro não significa que algo será melhor depois. Quem mostra 2 pesoas 2 medidas não tem credibilidade pra decidir nada.

Comment: Uma coisa que parece não haver entendimento por parte de alguns é que ofensa e desconforto são coisas muito diferentes. Quando existe uma situação onde duas pessoas estão em posições opostos uma delas ficará desconfortável. Só a ofensa merece punição, de forma democrática, não pode ser imposta por quem criou a regra. E obrigar alguém fazer algo só pode ocorrer por lei ou decisão judicial, porque houve um processo democrático pra se chegar ali. A SE está causando desconforto em um lado pra privilegiar outro. Não sendo ofensivo cada um faz o que quer e todos aprendem viver com a diversidade.

Comment: @Renan Falta ficar claro como as pessoas se posicionariam frente a casos concretos como esse seu exemplo da Joana. O debate na sala de mods e as mudanças no CoC dizem respeito a tratar as pessoas pelo gênero errado – *misgendering*. O posicionamento do Caleb pode ser discutível, mas o da Monica não. Ela nunca trataria alguém pelo gênero errado. E ao debater como poderia fazer para evitar tratar alguém pelo *número*, errado, não gênero – ela tem reservas quanto a tratar indivíduos por *they*, e tem gente que quer esse pronome –, foi deposta. Quem não foi nada amistoso na conversa foi a diretora

Comment: @bfavaretto "*Hoth said that they won't fix that bug in the code*" - Quem que é they?

Comment: @VictorStafusa Nesse caso é indefinido e em conformidade com a gramática. Mais um pouco de contexto: a Monica é escritora técnica, com excelente domínio do inglês (nativo, acredito). O que ela queria evitar era ter de usar plural para se referir a uma entidade claramente singular. Pelo menos eu entendi assim.

Comment: @bfavaretto Sim, entendo isso. Mas qualquer um que for ler essa sentença não vai imaginar que they se refere a Hoth, e sim a algum outro grupo. Isso vai além da gramática. Ao usar "they" sacrificar-se a clareza semântica. A solução mais simples seria reescrever a frase e evitar o pronome ou chutar o gênero de Hoth, mas se ambas as alternativas não serão mais toleradas, então só restará não dizer nada.

Comment: Exato @Victor, agora entendi seu ponto, e concordo. Você viu a declaração deles no *The Register*? Diz assim: *Monica Cellio (she/her) ...*. Se a meta final deles, com esse novo CoC ou um próximo, for querer que todos escrevam assim, perderam totalmente o senso da realidade. Uma coisa é garantir um ambiente inclusivo e respeitoso. Outra é ser autoritário em nome de ser inclusivo e respeitoso. Eles precisam equilibrar isso direito, porque desta vez estão pendendo pro lado errado. Pode ser que a saída da Aza tenha deixado a SE desestabilizada, ao ponto de acabarem descontando na Monica.

Comment: @bfavaretto na verdade, pelo que eu entendi, a Monica é proponente do uso de *they/them*. Ela diz isso no post no qual falou sobre a demoderação. Aconteceu outra discórdia que não era essa, que levou à "demissão". A falta de transparência da SE e a exigência de sigilo absoluto sobre o conteúdo das conversas no Teacher's Lounge levaram o caso até onde ele chegou.

Comment: Está tudo confuso e eu posso estar errado, mas parece que a Monica não quer usar o They. Eu não vi tudo no TL mas o que vi era lambança da SE e aos poucos foi ficando mais claro que eles erraram muito mais feio do que eu percebi inicialmente. De forma geral muitos dos funcionários da SE mereciam ser destituídos mais que a Monica, e não só por isso. Eu não quero gastar mais tempo com isso e não vou detalhar, mas eles não só não estão fazendo nada para avançar positivamente no que conta mas também estão criando novos problemas. Não são pessoas boas pra lidar com comunidades.

Comment: Quem era bom com isso e era quem tinha poder e ainda está lá nunca está envolvido nessas lambanças. Ele pode até ter decisões que podem ser contestadas e tenho minhas dúvidas se ele hoje não toma algumas contra sua própria vontade por ser algo determinado pela empresa, mas mesmo assim não causa mais problema ainda. O resumo de tudo é que as pessoas cada vez menos tem confiança no que a SE faz.

Comment: @Renan São dois debates, um sobre usar o *they* singular quando se refere a alguém indeterminado ou cujo gênero não se conhece. O caso dos não-binários que querem ser chamados de *they* seria um uso mais particular, recente e controverso -- ver [aqui](https://public.oed.com/blog/a-brief-history-of-singular-they/) e [aqui](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/singular-nonbinary-they)). Entendi que são debates que estão circulando em algumas culturas de língua inglesa, então toda a controvérsia tem esse contexto como fundo. E deve ter sutilezas que a gente de fora não consegue captar.

Comment: A SE tem o direito de aplicar o código de conduta que bem entender. Eu acho que na prática essa mudança nem deve fazer tanta diferença. É verdade que a Monica foi um pouco teimosa, mas nada diferente do normal que vejo nos debates da rede, e nunca desrespeitosa. Acho válido o argumento deles de que a Monica repense se no fundo não está sendo preconceituosa, mesmo que de maneira inconsciente. Mas a maneira como ela foi cortada foi muito feia. Se a intenção era dar um exemplo, que escolhessem alguém mais tóxico para punir.

Comment: O que mais vejo é a SE sendo teimosa. Eles já mentiram várias vezes e o tempo demonstrou isso, sempre pediram para confiar neles e quando as pessoas ,cansadas de tudo isso não aceitaram eles sempre disseram que não podiam fazer nada a não ser falar a verdade, que depois deu pra ver que não era de fato. Só tem um jeito de conseguirem mudar, o novo CEO fazer um *statement* claro de mudança e começar mudar os funcionários que criam esses problemas. Mas é só esperança. Eu queria ver tudo melhor, mas agora fico só na torcida.

Comment: @Renan [post bloquedo pelo Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/334248/revisions) ;)

Comment: Vale apontar que a [Monica nega veementemente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334248/an-update-to-our-community-and-an-apology#comment1092882_334248) a acusação do comunicado oficial.

Comment: @bfavaretto sim. Para complicar mais as coisas, já vi moderadores dizerem que ela não infringiu as regras e que em momento algum errou, e já vi moderadores dizerem que ela não apenas infringiu como fazia isso de forma constante e assediadora. Como a TL é sigilosa, quem não é moderador (a vasta maioria dos usuários da rede) jamais vai poder ver o que realmente foi dito.

Comment: Em algum lugar vi alguém dizendo que tentou se manter longe de vazamentos. Não quer dizer que existam, mas quem sabe. Há mais hackers em Araraquara do que imaginamos rsrsrs. Mas falando sério, mesmo que a sala fosse aberta é difícil ler a TL, tem muito ruído lá. Objetivamente o que foi dito pela Monica não foi discriminatório. Só que o clima estava pesado, e a SE sensibilizada e determinada a tomar alguma atitude. Pra entender todo o contexto particular de cada um que se posicionou naquele momento, precisaria ler meses de transcripts.

Comment: @Renan Quando disseste tudo isso de “Todo mundo que debate questões identitárias e de gênero tentar usar @ ou a letra `e` como vogal neutra não resolve nenhum problema, apenas cria mais problemas”, embora talvez tenha sido por acaso, explicaste 
muito bem a posição de Monica. Para ela é *uma questão puramente
gramatical* e nada mais. Se alguém te dissesse que com essa pessoa deverias
usar esses caracteres estranhos como mencionaste antes, que não são formas
gramaticais no teu próprio idioma mas apenas na lingua dela, o que farias?
Poderias realmente mudar a tua gramática? Monica não pôde.

Answer (score 9):

Obviamente não posso responder pela SE e por outros moderadores. Fiquei sabendo disto agora e ainda não processei tudo, então responderei o que me cabe e ainda especulando um pouco, não tome como algo firme..

Duvido que afete o SOpt diretamente em específico, pode afetar a rede como um todo. Se a SE começar tomar decisões sem critério ou por critérios duvidosos que vão contra o que a comunidade quer haverá uma debandada geral de mais gente de qualidade. Espero que ocorra o contrário. E devemos esperar mais um pouco para ter tudo mais claro.

Minha opinião de muito tempo é que a SE tem feito muita coisa errada há muito tempo (tem um marco específico onde começou e foi piorando), mas não posso dizer que este seja um caso que ela errou de novo ou está até acertando e algumas pessoas estão revoltadas sem causa, ou se tudo é neutro. O maior erro da SE é fazer quase nada e se preocupar com os problemas errados. Já teve até uns discursos (mais de uma vez) que desta vez é sério, que iam começar arrumar os problemas, e nada aconteceu.

Pode ser só que eles não lidaram bem com uma situação que até merecia uma ação nesse sentido. É impressionante como eles sempre erram o tom até quando estão com a razão.

Existe a versão de um lado, do outro e a verdade, podemos ter acesso às versões de todos os lados, mas a verdade é difícil de descobrir por isso não tenho como fazer afirmações mais diretas sobre a situação, talvez mais pra frente.

Particularmente gostaria de ver muita coisa melhorando mas não tenho mais esperanças, o que vier é lucro. A comunidade também parou de ajudar e o SOpt está em um estado bastante ruim, e piorou quando achei que tinha chego em um limite. Aconteceu tudo o que nós prevíamos se não fosse estabelecido um padrão rígido. Admito que talvez nem assim a situação estaria muito melhor, se as pessoas não colaboram não tem jeito de funcionar bem.

Eu já disse antes e repito que qualquer imposição da SE me empurrará para fora e sei que será acompanhado de outras pessoas. Se eles querem que algo aconteça precisam ter a concordância de quem faz isto funcionar.

Uma coisa que tem ficado mais claro é que a SE não está sequer respondendo demandas da comunidade, em alguns casos alegando que os funcionários estão recebendo *bullying* dos membros. Aí fica complicado resolver alguma coisa.

Para a SE está bom porque continuam gerando tráfego para estar entre os 40 sites mais acessados do mundo, posição semelhante se olharmos só o acesso no Brasil (imagino somando o tráfego do SOpt + SOen e quem sabe outros sites da rede, não tenho dados para falar, só falo do que está público). Seria bem legal se tivéssemos uma informação do tráfego do SOpt comparado com o do SOen no Brasil, e quem sabe de Portugal (O SO não aparece entre os 50). Há uma massa crítica de novas perguntas s respostas que faz o site andar mesmo não sendo uma internet melhor e tem algum conteúdo muito bom, quase todo produzido em um passado cada vez mais distante.

De tudo isso vou destacar um trecho que achei importante:

> I see a question and answer site as a useful complement to an encyclopedia, whose role Wikipedia fulfills. However, the way it is run now makes me doubt that Stack Exchange is a good place to build this library

Mas eu acredito que ainda pode ser revertido, mas muita coisa precisa mudar. Quem sabe [sob nova direção](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/09/24/announcing-stack-overflows-new-ceo-prashanth-chandrasekar/) possa começar mudar de vez, mas ele terá que mudar muita coisa, muita gente pra isto acontecer de fato.

Vamos ver com calma, mas isto é grave: [A very recent post asking people to go "on strike" was just deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334024/140010).

Em alguns momentos eu tenho vontade de começar fazer "operação tartaruga" mas porque sendo moderador e desagradando muita gente acaba sendo punido por essas pessoas, e nem sempre a SE dá atenção a algumas dessas coisas que algo poderia ser feito. Fica uma coisa assimétrica.

Postei para não deixar sem nada, mas posso editar a resposta a qualquer momento.

Comment: Achei isso: https://www.reddit.com/r/stackoverflow/comments/c6sw60/community_managers_explain_how_they_manage_stack/ no meio de um chat do meta.

Comment: Que confusão hein? Também só fiquei sabendo quando o Victor postou isto aqui. Enfim, concordo com o seu diagnóstico. Incrível mesmo a capacidade da SE de fazer lambança mesmo quando bem-intencionada.

Comment: Não duvido te mandarem embora por não agir de acordo com o "politicamente correto" deles. Considerarei isto um ato de extrema ingratidão por parte deles.

Comment: Sempre tive Monica como referencia de tato, imparcialidade e diplomacia. Parece tudo uma grande trapalhada e avacalhação. Troço triste de se ver.

Comment: \o/   Ele vive!       (cc @brasofilo)